# ArangoDB edge lookup cost

Tags: arangodb

Hi  I have below collections and relation

- broadcast (24,518 doc)
- videoGroup (5,699 doc)
- episode (124,893 doc)
- videoClip (485,878 doc)
- character (55,541 doc)

And Their collections has relation each other, below

broadcast has many videoGroup(m:n), so I create broadcastToVideoGroup Edge Collection
Collection
videoGroup has many episode(1:n), so I create videoGroupToEpisode EdgeCollection
episode has many videoClip(1:n), so I create episodeToVideoClip EdgeCollection

I fetched below query for all joined result

```
FOR b IN broadcast
    FILTER b.reg_title > NULL
    return merge(b, {series: (
        FOR s IN OUTBOUND b._id tvToSeries
            return merge(s, {episode: (
                FOR e IN OUTBOUND s._id seriesToEpisode
                    return merge(e, {clip: (
                        FOR c IN OUTBOUND e._id episodeToClip
                            return c
                    )})
            )})
    )})
```

The explain is below

```
Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType                   Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode                 1   * ROOT
  2   EnumerateCollectionNode   24518     - FOR b IN broadcast   /* full collection scan */
  7   SubqueryNode              24518       - LET #2 = ...   /* subquery */
  3   SingletonNode                 1         * ROOT
  4   CalculationNode               1           - LET #13 = b.`_id`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: b : broadcast */
  5   TraversalNode                 5           - FOR c  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND #13 /* startnode */  broadcastToCharacter
  6   ReturnNode                    5           - RETURN c
 24   SubqueryNode              24518       - LET #11 = ...   /* subquery */
  8   SingletonNode                 1         * ROOT
  9   CalculationNode               1           - LET #17 = b.`_id`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: b : broadcast */
 10   TraversalNode                 1           - FOR s  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND #17 /* startnode */  broadcastToVideoGroup
 21   SubqueryNode                  1           - LET #9 = ...   /* subquery */
 11   SingletonNode                 1             * ROOT
 12   CalculationNode               1               - LET #21 = s.`_id`   /* attribute expression */
 13   TraversalNode                25               - FOR e  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND #21 /* startnode */  videoGroupToEpisode
 18   SubqueryNode                 25               - LET #7 = ...   /* subquery */
 14   SingletonNode                 1                 * ROOT
 15   CalculationNode               1                   - LET #25 = e.`_id`   /* attribute expression */
 16   TraversalNode                 8                   - FOR c  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND #25 /* startnode */  episodeToClip
 17   ReturnNode                    8                   - RETURN c
 19   CalculationNode              25               - LET #29 = MERGE(e, { "clips" : #7 })   /* simple expression */
 20   ReturnNode                   25               - RETURN #29
 22   CalculationNode               1           - LET #31 = MERGE(s, { "episodes" : #9 })   /* simple expression */
 23   ReturnNode                    1           - RETURN #31
 25   CalculationNode           24518       - LET #33 = MERGE(b, { "character" : #2, "videoGroup" : #11 })   /* simple expression */   /* collections used: b : broadcast */
 26   ReturnNode                24518       - RETURN #33

Indexes used:
 By   Type   Collection        Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields        Ranges
  5   edge   broadcastToCharacter     false    false        19.42 %   [ `_from` ]   base OUTBOUND
 10   edge   broadcastToVideoGroup        false    false        90.89 %   [ `_from` ]   base OUTBOUND
 13   edge   videoGroupToEpisode   false    false         3.99 %   [ `_from` ]   base OUTBOUND
 16   edge   episodeToClip     false    false        11.55 %   [ `_from` ]   base OUTBOUND
```

In execution plan, I wonder that why plan is not 1 but 25 at id 13(TravasalNode) Estimation.
Is not 1 for ArangoDB edge collection lookup?